# Error when trying to build and run Docker container in TeamCity

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, teamcity

I want to build my Android Dockerfile and after this build step run some another step.

The step is simple build the Docker image:
[image]

So the command is simple:

```
docker build -t android-build:android-template -f Dockerfile .
```

My Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6604631_latest.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=29 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3 \

RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip

RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --licenses

RUN $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME --update

RUN yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME \
    "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}"

RUN mkdir /application

WORKDIR /application
```

Unfortunately, build is failing just on this first step:
[image]

The whole error log is as below:

```
 time="2020-07-18T22:01:27Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
00:01:27
  time="2020-07-18T22:01:27Z" level=error msg="Can't add file /opt/buildagent/work/da45177e2c517d09/.git/index to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe"
00:01:27
  time="2020-07-18T22:01:27Z" level=error msg="Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe"
00:01:27
  error during connect: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=fvz9t2pm9dkmopc06bf6yxqa5&shmsize=0&t=android-build%3Aandroid-template&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: context canceled
00:01:27
  Process exited with code 1
00:01:28
  Process exited with code 1 (Step: Build a Docker container (Command Line))
00:01:28
  Step Build a Docker container (Command Line) failed
```

I am running this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  tcs:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    container_name: teamcity-server
    ports:
      - "8111:8111"
    volumes:
      - teamcity/server/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - teamcity/server/logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
  tca:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent
    depends_on:
      - tcs
    container_name: teamcity-agent
    environment:
      - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
      - SERVER_URL=http://tcs:8111/
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /teamcity/agent:/data/teamcity_agent/conf
```

on Mac: macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5

I am not a DevOps guy, can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, I think you need to mount the hosts `/var/run/docker.sock` into your build agent.

From command line, it would look like this:

```
docker run -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2019.2.4 /bin/bash
```

So in docker compose, I'm guessing you will need something like this:

```
  volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Second, there was a change in [version 2020.1](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/) where it no longer runs as root.

> Since version 2020.1, TeamCity agent Docker images run under a non-root user. Refer to our upgrade notes for information on possible affected use cases.

so you if you use a 2020 version of the build agent or later, you may need to specify root user in your docker compose in order to docker in docker to work.  So in docker compose I think you would add `user: root` under the image line.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately after your suggestion I am getting another error ```Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "RUN". Must be of the form: name=value```.Maybe you know how to resolve with my current setup?

Comment: That sounds like it was able to get past the docker daemon error and now there is a problem in your Dockerfile. Are you able to build you Dockerfile locally?

Comment: I don't think you ever need to both `/var/run/docker.sock` from the host and declare `DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start`.  One uses your host's docker daemon, the other starts a docker daemon inside the Agent's container.  You can't communicate with two daemons, you only need access to one.